# Unable to insert message into Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am facing below error when I try to insert message into Kafka via Producer API

```
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for metadata_notification-0: 30036 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

What could be the issue with this ?

More code goes below :

```
 protected void produceMessage(String topic, String orgId, Map<String, byte[]> header, String payload) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In Produce Message Method");
        final Producer<String, String> producer = createMetaProducer();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            List<Header> messageHeaders = header.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new RecordHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println("Send header");
            LOGGER.info("Sending headers:");
            for(Header mh: messageHeaders) {
                LOGGER.info("{}: {}",mh.key(),new String(mh.value()));
            }
            final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, null, orgId, payload, messageHeaders);
            RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
            long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            System.out.printf("sent record(key=%s value=%s) " +
                            "meta(partition=%d, offset=%d) time=%d\n",
                    record.key(), record.value(), metadata.partition(),
                    metadata.offset(), elapsedTime);
        } finally {
            producer.flush();
            producer.close();
        }
    }
```

At this point as below , it fails and gives our error has above - TimeoutException

```
 final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, null, orgId, payload, messageHeaders);
            RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
```

In MY Case kafka is docker image

Comment: please add the code...

Comment: Please add more details, code and the full error stack.

Comment: This error might be a problem with the brokers, not your code

Comment: I have added the code , please help

Comment: Did you make sure your Kafka brokers are up and running correctly? If yes, can I see the configuration you set for Kafka? Change the timeout to 60000ms.

Answer (score 0):

You might hit bug [KAFKA-5886](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5886). For more details see [KIP-91](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-91+Provide+Intuitive+User+Timeouts+in+The+Producer). To avoid the issue, you an increase `request.timeout.ms`.

Comment: Can we insert message into kafka docker image wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.1  from external producer Api

Comment: @user5702955 Please ensure that you are exposing the kafka ports in your docker yml file.